# Java why can I not add to this ArrayList

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends

I have a class with a generic T. Then I create an ArrayList with a generic that holds T or any of its subobjects. I assign it to an ArrayList with generic T. Why can I not add to it. Here is the code snippet:

```
ArrayList<? extends T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
T t; //yes I know it is null currently, but this is the idea
list.add(t); //will not compile
```

I know it will throw a NullPointer, but that's not the issue. Why won't it let me add a T object to an ArrayList declared that it can be instantiated with an ArrayList of type T and thus instantiated with type T.

-Thanks

P.S. I did not put the code in the snippet but it is in a class with generic T defined.

Comment: But what is T? You need to define it somehow? If you have a generic class, MyClass<T> then it should work.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I do have that class. I put in the text that I have a generic T in a class already. This is just the snippet.

Comment: @nvioli Then how can I do the intended effect?

Comment: What is the intended effect? The code you have now is intended to be read from, not written to.

Comment: Per the linked answer, "Sorry, but you can't."

Comment: Why not just use the simple ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: @SilvioMayolo the intended effect is to have an ArrayList that can take in an object of type t or a subtype. Never a super type. So for example, on runtime, it takes in some generic. Whatever that generic is, the ArrayList holds it. But that ArrayList can only take in generics that as numbers or subclasses of numbers. So it could take in doubles, but only doubles, or ints, and only ints, but never Strings. So on runtime, it takes in whatever the generic is, but the generic has to be a Number or a sub type.

Comment: @Magnus Cause what if I only want it to be numbers... not Strings. I wouldn't do ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<>() because I want it to take any generic number, doubles, ints, etc.

Comment: `ArrayList<Number>` is exactly what you want. That's the whole point of subtyping.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<>() a.add(new Double(5)); will not work.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder `ArrayList<Number> a = new ArrayList<>();` followed by `a.add(new Double(5));` absolutely **will** work.

Comment: @Jordan typo, thanks. I don't see why ? extends blah is necessary then, if you can't even add anything to it.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder You should read the two other questions that have been linked at the top of this question.  The first one goes into a ton of detail about this exact issue, and explains in detail why you can't add anything to a list when you use `<? extends X>`.

Comment: @Jordan I did actually, it does not explain why this is necessary, I do not think.

Comment: It absolutely does. Especially the PECS dup, which explains both the extends and super notation. And the use case is absolutely not what you're trying to do right now.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time.